# Combine multiple tables into one table

Tags: powershell

When running this powershell command

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.txt
```

You get multiple tables in the output, One Table per directory.

What method can I use to combine multiple tables into one table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to select the properties you want. Otherwise, you get a separate listing for each sub folder.  You could try something like this:

PS C:>dir c:\scripts -recurse -include *.txt | Select Mode,LastWriteTime,Length,FullName | format-table -auto

Comment: You have to think in terms of objects, not tables of text then it is much easier to figure out. Glad it helped.

Comment: Furthermore, this is just the effect of the formatting system to show you the data in a text console.  If you want another format, just ask PowerShell!